# JSON response with strong type values via PHP

Tags: php, json

We develop rest api for our service. And now we need to implement response in JSON format.
We get data from db, and encode it to JSON. But some time value return in different type. For example:

`"category_id":"12"` or `"category_id":12`

So sometimes it returns as `string` and sometimes it returns as `numeric`.
And an other situation sometimes we get response as an `array`, and sometimes as `associative array`.

Is it possible some how to set strong type for the value? Maybe you recommend some third party tools.

Comment: just be sure that your values in correct type before `json_encode`. `intval($int)` is always int after it. also there are several flags about this, like `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`, `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`.

Comment: json_encode uses whatever the internal type in php is. `json_encode(42)` -> `42`. `json_encode("42")` -> `"42"`. string in, string out. int in, int out, yada yada yada

Comment: Do you use header  application/json?

Comment: @koredalin yes. The problem that data type from db could be numeric or string. So the question was is it possible somehow to set strong type return value. Maybe in mapper oк somewhere.

Comment: You can format the php data with `intval(trim($variable));` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to treat all numeric value as number and return data type number then you have to use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option.
like following:

`json_encode($arrays, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`